# How to `read byte` to read an object between Objective-C and Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets, byte

I need to exchange an object between Objective-C client and Java Server. I ask my friends how it can implement, and he answer me that `read byte` is the way to go. But how can it implements? How can I know the variable length, and related information? Thanks.

Comment: It's relatively meaningless to say "exchange objects" between Java and Objective-C without specifying some sort of extra-linguistic object concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of serialization format. You could use a text-based format such as XML or JSON, decoding it appropriately (whether by hand or not). Alternatively, there are various portable binary-based serialization formats available, such as [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com) which has an [Objective-C port](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers).

Answer (score 1):

Objects in different language probably can't be exchanged easily. Instead of sending Java/ObjC objects to Java/ObjC program, I will suggest you to actually send it as some other string structure - maybe XML/JSON. And then reconstruct back the Java/ObjC objects from the XML/JSON.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of options here.  [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [protocol buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), ...  There's even a [giant list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats) of possibilities.